# Do I have to Dispose the SQLiteCommand objects?

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-3.5, system.data.sqlite

How do I treat the `SQLiteCommand` object,
do I **have to** call `Dispose()` after `ExecuteScalar`, `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteReader` or not?

The documentation example on [SQLiteCommand](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.html) doesn't dispose it whilst
in the [SQLiteTransaction](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteTransaction.html) the example disposes the SQLiteCommand object.

I always close the data reader object though. My application accesses the db from many threads.

Mostly I am interested in not leaking connections or disturbing SQLite. I am aware of `using` and `IDisposable` usage

Comment: Rule of thumb: if it's disposable, dispose it when you no longer need it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's best-practise to dispose everything that implements `IDisposable` as soon as you're finished with it because it might use unmanaged resources.

This should be done with the [`using`-statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) since it wraps the code that uses this object and because it disposes it also in case of an exception.

```
using(var con = new SQLiteConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con))
{
    con.Open();
    // ...
} // also closes the connection
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is disposable, dispose it if you will not use it again.
The best would be, to use using

```
using(SQLiteCommand cmd as new SQLiteCoammand())
{
   ...
}
```

So it will be disposed automatically when leaving the using scope.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString))
using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
   command.CommandText = "...";
   connection.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Not calling dispose on the command won't do anything too bad. However calling Dispose on it will supress the call to the finalizer, making calling dispose a performance enhancement.

Comment: It seems that it **does** actually do something bad. Although I am not really sure why. Just refactoring my DAOs and expect the issue to go away (I hate this kind of magic but in this case I don't want to dig into SQLite source)

Answer (score 1):

The using statement will call Dispose on an object even if an exception occurs that bypasses the code that calls Close(). This way you don't have to write a try/finally block just to close the readers or the connection. You also avoid this 1-in-100 case where you forget to write the proper finally block.

Such 1-in-100 cases have a tendency to occur much more frequently than one would think